# Java SOAPConnection Calling an Https ASMX service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https, tls1.2

Good Afternoon,

I have been working on this for a few hours now and I have Googled and Googled this with no luck. I have an ASMX service that resides on an https url. I can hit it via the browser with no issue and see the web methods and WSDL. I have tried several methods to try and connect to the endpoint via java but keep receiving the same 403 forbidden error.

Here is my current code:

```
public static String getInspectorSchedulesProd(){
    //Local Variable Declaration
    //List<InspectorSchedule> returnValue = null;
    String returnValue = "";
    //String url = "";
    String content = "";
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection connection = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage soapResponse = null;
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;

    try{
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = null;

        // Create SSL context and trust all certificates
        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        //content = "Current SSL Provider: " + sslContext.getProvider().getName() + "\n";

        for(java.security.Provider Item : java.security.Security.getProviders()){
            //content += Item.getName() + "\n";
        }

        javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAll = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] {new TrustAllCertificates()};

        sslContext.init(null, trustAll, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        // Set trust all certificates context to HttpsURLConnection
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        // Open HTTPS connection
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://www.twiddy.com/webservices/rnsportalws1.asmx");
        httpsConnection = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Trust all hosts
        httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHosts());

        // Connect
        httpsConnection.connect();

        content = "Content Type: " + httpsConnection.getContentType() + "\nResponse Message:" + httpsConnection.getResponseMessage() + "\nAllow User Interaction:" + httpsConnection.getAllowUserInteraction();

        // Send HTTP SOAP request and get response
        //connection = javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();

        //soapResponse = connection.call(createGetInspectorsSchedulesSoapMessageProd(), "https://url/portalws1.asmx");

        //Write the results from the request into the output stream
        //soapResponse.writeTo(out);

        //Convert the stream into a string
        //content = new String(out.toByteArray());

        returnValue = content;

        // Close connection
        //connection.close();
        httpsConnection.disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        returnValue = org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
    }

    return  returnValue;
}

private static class TrustAllCertificates implements javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
    }
}

private static class TrustAllHosts implements javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}

private static javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage createGetInspectorsSchedulesSoapMessageProd() throws Exception{
    //Local Variable Declaration
    String serverURI = "";
    javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory messageFactory = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage soapMessage = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart soapPart = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope envelope = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody soapBody = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement soapBodyElem = null;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement soapMethodParam = null;
    javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders headers = null;

    //Set the Server Uri Namespace
    serverURI = "http://url/PortalWS1";

    //Init the Message Factory
    messageFactory = javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance();

    //Init the Message
    soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

    //Init the SOAP-specific portion of a Message
    soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    //Create the envelope that will wrap the message
    envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("PortalWS1Soap", serverURI);

    //Get an instance of the body of the message
    soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    //Add the Soap Method we wish to call
    soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetInspectorScheds", "PortalWS1Soap");

    //Add the Access Key Parameter
    soapMethodParam = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("strAccessKey", "PortalWS1Soap");
    soapMethodParam.addTextNode("SF!435gFW");

    //Get an instance of the http message headers
    headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();

    //Append our soap Action header to the message
    headers.addHeader("soapAction", "https://url/webservices/portalws1.asmx/GetScheds");

    //Save our chnages
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1):

i use 1st and 2nd classes from [here](https://alesaudate.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/how-to-dynamically-select-a-certificate-alias-when-invoking-web-services/)
HostnameVerifier class from AXIS as

```
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return fias.HostnameVerifier.DEFAULT.verify(hostname, session);
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.connect();
```

and classes from [here](https://gist.github.com/kdelfour/b2a449a1bac23e3baec8) for send SOAP
make your own keyStore and trustStore
i make connecting by IP and i use aliases for keys (they equal in stores)
don't forget use for debug **System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");**
it works for me
PS: [my other simple method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414367/simple-soap-client-ssl-connection-error) does not work for SOAP yet ((
PSS: for SOAPAction header i used uri like your serverURI. i mean namespace+action